# jQuery carousel plugin from scratch

Tags: jquery, this, each, carousel

**Description**: I need to build a jQuery/javascript carousel plugin from scratch. The carrousel functionality will be called by an extended jQuery function (`$.fn`) I will call carrousel() or something of the sort. Depending on how I build the method it would be applied to either the `div` containing the pictures that will make the carousel or to the arrows (or whatever the developer defines as "prev", "next" buttons) that move the carousel. 
The same carrousel() method will be called whatever users clicks "previous" or "next" and my code will decide whether it should slide the pictures to the right or to the left depending on which the user clicked.

I am using the data object to store the images and keep everything wrapped in the same object.

**Problem**: This plugin needs to work regardless of the number of carousels I have on my page (I have three). I am using jQuery .each to loop through the arrows that will have the carrousel and when users click on that arrow I need to get that specific object using either `$(this)` or `this` and move the images in the parent `div` accordingly. For some reason, the click event on `$(this)` does not work. When I click the arrows I cannot see anything in console (see code below).

On a second version, I am looping through the `div`s that have the images, getting the arrows inside those `div`s, and trying to do something with the arrows. This also doesn't work.

**Question**: how do I get each individual arrow on the collection of arrows I have and do stuff when they are clicked? (I believe I am not using `$(this)` correctly).

Note: The `div`s with the pictures have a `data-images` attribute containing the images.
Note: The arrows are the `img` tags with `data-direcion` attributes (previous or next)

Here is the code I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<article class="resources">
        <section class="resources_headings">
            <div>
                <h2>2/ Resources</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Our Physicians have the latest tools at their fingertips.</h4>
            </div>  
        </section>
        <section class="innovator">
            <div>
                <h3>Innovator</h3>
                <p>Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl</p>
            </div>
            <div data-images='["images/resources/innovator_s.jpg","images/resources/results_s.jpg","images/resources/tests_s.jpg","images/resources/lab_s.jpg"]' class="innovator_wrapper slider">
                <img data-direction="previous" src="images/icons/chevron_left.png" alt="chevron_left" class="chevron_resources innovator_previous mobile direction">
                <img data-direction="next" src="images/icons/chevron_right.png" alt="chevron_right" class="chevron_resources innovator_next mobile direction">
                <img src="images/resources/innovator_s.jpg" alt="innovator" class="resources_images innovator">
                <div id="caption_overlay">
                    <span>New technologies</span><img src="images/icons/chevron_left.png" alt="chevron_left" class="chevron_resources innovator_previous"><img src="images/icons/chevron_right.png" alt="chevron_right" class="chevron_resources innovator_next">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="facilities">
            <div>
                <h3>Facilities</h3>
                <p>Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-images='["images/resources/lab_s.jpg","images/resources/innovator_s.jpg","images/resources/results_s.jpg","images/resources/tests_s.jpg", "images/resources/physicians_s.jpg"]' class="facilities_wrapper slider">
                <img data-direction="previous" src="images/icons/chevron_left.png" alt="chevron_left" class="chevron_resources facilities_previous mobile direction"><img data-direction="next" src="images/icons/chevron_right.png" alt="chevron_right" class="chevron_resources facilities_next mobile direction">
                <img src="images/resources/hallway_s.jpg" alt="hallway" class="resources_images facilities">
                <div id="caption_overlay">
                    <span>World Class Facilities</span><img src="images/icons/chevron_left.png" alt="chevron_left" class="chevron_resources facilities_previous"><img src="images/icons/chevron_right.png" alt="chevron_right" class="chevron_resources facilities_next">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="simulation">
            <div>
                <h3>Training Simulation</h3>
                <p>Tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Phasellus leo dolor, nullam accumsan</p>
            </div>
            <div data-images='["images/resources/innovator_s.jpg","images/resources/lab_s.jpg", "images/resources/results_s.jpg","images/resources/tests_s.jpg"]' class="simulation_wrapper slider">
                <img data-direction="previous" src="images/icons/chevron_left.png" alt="chevron_left" class="chevron_resources simulation_previous mobile direction"><img data-direction="next" src="images/icons/chevron_right.png" alt="chevron_right" class="chevron_resources simulation_next mobile direction">
                <img src="images/resources/lab_s.jpg" alt="lab" class="resources_images simulation">
                <div id="caption_overlay">
                    <span>Real Life Simulations</span><img src="images/icons/chevron_left.png" alt="chevron_left" class="chevron_resources simulation_previous"><img src="images/icons/chevron_right.png" alt="chevron_right" class="chevron_resources simulation_next">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
```

**jQuery version 1: loop through the arrows ('img.direction') and get $(this) when it is clicked (not using the $fn here for clarity):**

```
$(function() {
  $('img.direction').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);//returns the objects for the 6 arrows
    console.log(self);//works fine

    //get the slider directions (previous or next)
    var directions = $(this).data('direction');//works fine

   $(this).on('click', function(){ //this doesn't work
        console.log('directions');//nothing shows on the console when I click the arrows
    });

    //get images in each div
    var slideContainer = $(this).closest('.slider').data('images');//this works
    console.log(slideContainer);//this works
});
```

});

**jQuery version 2: loop through the divs (.slider) that have the pictures, get the arrows inside that div, use $(this) to get the data-direction, and do move the images depending on the direction:**

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider').each(function(){
    //get images in each div
    var images = $(this).data('images');//works
    console.log(images.length);

    //get the slider controllers (direction arrows)
    var directions = $(this).find('img.direction');//works
    console.log(directions);

        //loop through all arrows and get them by index
        directions.each(function(index){
            // console.log(directions[index]);

            $(this).on('click',function(){//doesn't work
                var direction = $(this).data('direction');
                console.log('direction');
                if(direction==='next'){
                    console.log('next');
                }
                else{
                    console.log('previous');
                }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

THANKS A LOT!

Comment: can provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Fiddle wouldn't be useful because the code is not finished yet. I have a pure javascript carrousel in place already but it is too verbose and only works on my code. I need to make it as DRY as possible.

Comment: why are you using this instead of self ?

Comment: In that case it doesn't make any difference, Prolly. Both self and $(this) refer to the same thing. I stored $(this) in a variable just for performance issues (I can call $(this) just once and then reference the variable where it is stored instead of keep asking the code to go get $(this) every time it runs).

Comment: trust me playing with $(this) is very dangerous it is better to cache it as you did , and use it directly.

Comment: Thanks. I will. But this is not the issue on the code.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$(".slider .direction").click(function(){
    var direction = $(this).data("direction");
    var images = $(this).parent().data("images");
    console.log(direction, images);
});
```

Somewhat working Fiddle (no images):
http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/40optfdw/

Comment: The fiddle is not working. What I have is very similar to this. In this case, $(this) is a collection of jQuery objects because there are multiple DOM elements with the same tag.

Comment: For me it correctly prints out the direction and the images array. Is it not what you want? After you got the array you can do other things like determine which image to display, etc.

Comment: I can see the console now. For some reason it didn't work before. I will try this piece of code. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on my code though. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: In your question you posted two examples, both loops through all the sliders. What I wrote here has no loops, and you would only need to run it once no matter how many siders you have on the page.

Comment: It is not easy to see why it isn't working for you without some actual code. Maybe you could create a fiddle like others have suggested.

Comment: The code is exactly the same as what I wrote here, alan0xd7. When I use a class that is specific for one button for instance, I get the console to work. When I use the generic class .direction, which is applied to many buttons, the console doesn't print anything. So, if I select the class .innovator_next on click, it works but the class .directions doesn't.

Comment: Problem solved. I was targeting only the mobile arrows so it didn't work on desktop. Thanks!